# How can i separate one function, and will call it to all of my controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one function, it is a very long function, this function needs to be run in all of my controllers, in the index function to be specific, so that in every load of my controller this function will be run. I tried to use `include` but it did not work. I am using HMVC as my pattern.

I know that this is not a good idea but, here is the look of my function.

```
public function sample(){
            foreach($this->First_model->getID() as $data)
            {
                if($this->First_model->getNewData($data["id"]) == 0)
                {
                    if((date('d')) == $data["month"])
                   {
                        $in = date_create($data["date_of_activation"]);
                        $end_date = date_modify(date_create($in->format('Y-m-' . $data["month"])),"+1 month")->format('Y-m-d');

                        if($this->First_model->check_history($data["id"]) >=1)
                        {
                            $price = $this->First_model->getElectricity_with_history($data["id"],$data["date_of_activation"],$end_date);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $price = $this->First_model->getElectricity_no_history($data["id"],$data["date_of_activation"],$end_date);

                        }

                        if($this->First_model->check_data($data["id"])== 0)
                         {
                            $data = array(
                                "id" => $data["id"],
                                "is_updated" => "0",
                                "total" => $price->price
                            );

                            $this->First_model->insert_data($data);
                         }
                   }
                }
                else
                {

                   if((date('d')) == $data["month"])
                   {
                        $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day - 1 month"));
                        $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day"));

                        $price = 0;
                        if($this->First_model->check_history($data["id"]) >=1)
                        {
                            $price = $this->First_model->getValue_history($data["id"],$start,$end);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                             $price = $this->First_model->getElectricity_no_history($data["id"],$start,$end);

                        }

                        if($this->First_model->check_if_has($data["id"])== 0)
                         {
                            $data = array(
                                "id" => $data["id"],
                                "is_updated" => "0",
                                "total" => $price->price
                            );


                            $this->First_model->insert_data($data);
                         }
                   }
                }
            }
}
```

is there a way that I can call this for all of my controllers? so instead of putting this very long function in my every Inde of my controllers.

Comment: HI, I can't understand your title. Can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to core folder under the application then create a file named `MY_Controller.php`

then write this code:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

     class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
      {
        public function sample(){
             echo "Hello World!";  
        }
      }
```

as you can see the code above you class **MY_Controller** extends to CI's built in Controller which is **CI_Controller**. All you can do next is extend your **New_Controller** to **MY_Controller** so you can use you function dynamically.

write something like this.

```
<?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

         class New_Controller extends MY_Controller
          {
            public function index(){
                 $this->sample(); //calling your function.  
            }
          }
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: hi, can I also do this for my Models?

Comment: @JanessaBautista, yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base controller class which all your other controllers extend, you can define the index method there.

```
class BaseController
{
    public function index() {
        // code that you want to run in every controller
    }    
}
```

If a child class needs to provide additional functionality, you can override the index method, call the parent index method there to invoke the base functionality, then write more code to define whatever else it needs to do beyond that.

```
class SomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index() {
        parent::index();
        // code specific to the child controller
    }
}
```

I haven't really looked too much at what your specific function does, to be honest, but this pattern can work well to solve the general problem you described.